# 2 drives down in a few months, What should i replace?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, filesystem-corruption

I've recently had 2 7200RPM SATA Disk Drives go in the span of about 2 months. The first i put down to an old drive so i removed it and took the hit. The second was not so old.

After inspecting the first drive it looks like the partition structure was corrupted. I've managed to restore it and the drive looks ok. I've yet to run a full test on the drive to validate it's ok.

The drives are not raided at all. I'm simply using the machine for storage of data.

It's also running Windows 10, with an Intel Core i7 2600K (sandy bridge) CPU running in a Gigabyte GA-Z68X-UD3-B3 Z68 Socket 1155.

IT's also got an SSD for the OS which has remained unaffected.

Anyone got any idea's what i should be looking to replace?

Comment: Are you using the right type of drive for the job? I had a NAS with a Seagate (I think) but there were 2 types of drive, a "green" and a "red". I put the wrong one in, and it died very quickly!

Comment: What brand of disk? What do the SMART values look like? You might simply be unlicky

Comment: One drive is 640GB WD drive (the oldest), the other is a 2TB Samsung drive. They are not in a NAZ just ion the Large PC with spacing between then.

Comment: It _could_ always be bad luck, after all. Even if hard drives die seldom, with the large numbers of people and hard drives in the world, _some people_ will get a double hit just by chance.

Answer (score 1):

We had a few computers that chewed drives like you wouldn't believe.

In the end, we put it down to heat.  Drives not adequately ventilated.

So I would check the ventilation in your case, check fans are working, and check the drives are not too close together (if you can).

Comment: Thanks I'll check my fans are ok.
I've removed both drives now while i try and recover what's on them.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put another SATA controller in, or else if the motherboard already features more than one SATA controller, I'd move the drives from the controller they were on to a new one, and see if that makes a difference. I have an X58 board that features a standard SATA II controller integrated, with another integrated Marvell controller for SATA III functionality. The Marvell controller is such an absolute dog that it regularly underperforms the SATA II controller, and on top of that actually has caused BSODs and corruption on more than one occasion. Moving my drives to the SATA II controller and an Asmedia PCI-E Sata controller addon card stopped the issues immediately.

Comment: Thanks i was wondering if the SATA controller on the motherboard was the issue or the power supply. Once i've recovered the data from the drive i'll have a play with it on my machine.